# How do I access nginx header variables in meteor

Tags: meteor, nginx

In my nginx config I've got proxy_pass set to my meteor app.  I'm also setting some header variables using proxy_set_header.  How do I get access to these variables in my meteor app?

In my main.js on the server I've tried a ton of things in  `Meteor.onConnection()`, but haven't been able to see the values of the variables set by nginx.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get the values from the headers for http requests with Webapp.connectHandlers or Webapp.rawConnectHandlers

```js
// server/main.js
Meteor.startup(() => {
      WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.headers);
        next();
      });
    }
```